# Finding spring constant

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

I have to rearrange the equation:

$$T=2\pi \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$$

To find the spring constant $k$.

The answer I got is $\frac{T^2 - m}{ 4\pi^2}.$

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$T=2\pi \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$$
$$\frac{T^2}{4\pi^2}=\frac{m}{k}$$

$$\frac{k}{m}=\frac{4\pi^2}{T^2}$$

Are you able to solve for $k$?

Comment: K = (4pi$^2$m) / T$^2$. Is this correct ?

Comment: yes, you are right. can you spot the error in your initial working? it is important to learn from previous mistakes. =)

Comment: Yes I have thank you (: